# Merge all files from directory tree

Tags: files, 15.04, merge

I have a directory called /home/foobar/ which contain numerous text files in numerous sub directories. I need to generate a file which has the merged content of all the files inside this directory structure.

The order in which the files are merged does not matter. I can copy all the files to one directory first and merge then, but in that case the solution must take into account that the files do not have unique names.

Comment: How do you propose to identify the files to be concatenated? do you want to concatenate every file in the tree? or only those files with a .txt extension? or files whose mimetype identifies them as text?

Comment: I need to merge all the files.

Comment: Do you need a delimiter between the file content of the files in the output file? Give me a ping with @A.B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple task for `find` and `cat`:

```
 find <path_to_files> -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} cat {} >> merged
```

The content of all files in `<path_to_files>` and in all sub-folders will be *added to `merged`*. Therefore remove `merged` for each new run of the command.

Answer (score -1):

This should work (replacing `path/to/dir` with the path to the base directory):

```
for i in $(find /path/to/dir -type "f" ); do cat "$i">>OUTPUT.txt;done
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I get terminal full of error messages from cat saying the file doesn't exist and OUTPUT.TXT remains empty.

Sample of output:
cat: mail_: No such file or directory
cat: see: No such file or directory
cat: transcript: No such file or directory
cat: for: No such file or directory
cat: details-89809.txt: No such file or directory

Comment: do your file names have spaces in them. Try running: `find /path/to/dir -type "f"` and paste a couple of examples in the comments.

Comment: Yes, filenames and the directory names (of the sub directories) have spaces.  Outputs: cat: mail_: No such file or directory
cat: see: No such file or directory
cat: transcript: No such file or directory
cat: for: No such file or directory
cat: details-84894.txt: No such file or directory

Comment: Ok, sorry I am not used to spaces in file names. Add double quotes around the `$i`. See edit above.

Comment: I tried that, same result, unfortunately.